# how to create django model by pressing button

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am fairly new django user a few months of project creation and messing around with it, and I have created models before using forms, but this would be my first time trying to create one using just a button, and I have no idea how to do that, I looked for examples on stackOverFlow and I found a few but I couldn't figure out how to apply them to my project

I have a products model that uses a category model

```
class Category(models.Model):

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_friendly_name(self):
    return self.friendly_name


class Product(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
sku = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
description = models.TextField()
has_tiers = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
favorites = models.ManyToManyField(
    User, related_name='product_favorites', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

and I have a favorite model

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
"""
A Favorite model so users can save products as their favorites
"""
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want that when a user is on the products_details.html page, which is just a normal page with the product details displayed nothing major, the user could click a button that says "add to favorite" and that button would go to the url, which would go to the needed view, I know how to do all that, what I don't know is how to create that view code that adds the Product and the User who clicked the button to Favorite model, thats where I hope to get some assistance

as mentioned I looked around on stackOverFlow, and I found a few questions, but couldn't figure out how to solve my problem, I think I found a work around, but I would still like to learn this way of creating models with just pressing a button instead of filling out a form, like I have before

EDIT: needed to change the user field in my favorite model from OneToOneField to a foreign key to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example of how you'd set up something like that.
I used a `<a>` / Link in the template block, but you've just got to goto the URL that url template tag generates.

##### Urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('add_to_favorites/<int:product_id>', views.add_to_favorites, name='add_to_favorites'),
]
```

##### View.py (super basic)

```py
def add_to_favorites(request, product_id):
    # Current user can *always* be grabbed in the view with `request.user` 
    #   Note: May run into issues if the user is not logged in

    Favorite.objects.get_or_create(product_id=product_id, user=request.user)

    # maybe do a redirect, or render different page
```

##### Template Button

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add_to_favorites' product_id=product.pk %}">Add to Favorite</a>

<!--
    This is the URL you need: 

    {% url 'add_to_favorites' product_id=product.pk %}

    'product' being the Var you threw the Product Object in to render the Details
--->
```

If you want it seamless, it might be a good idea to look into Javascript/Jquery & AJAX, and just POST to that URL

Comment: I actually thought of this a few minutes after posting a the question and I am getting, IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "favorites_favorite_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
which quickly destroyed my hope that I solved it myself, also I have my page set up that only logged in users can access it so no need to worry about users not being logged in

Comment: Could you double check your DB is up to date with: `python manage.py makemigrations` & `python manage.py migrate`?- that might be the issue, cause I don't see any uniques in the Code you provided.

Comment: I just did, and everything is up to date, I am using allauth for the users to register if that changes anything

Comment: found the problem I was using a OneToOneField in my favorites model, after I change to to a foreign key everything works, just like you said

Comment: @Sir.Breezy good!- cause I was freakin **dumbfounded** and naturally now I see it